# Can any pod assume an AKS managed identity and get access to Azure resources?

Tags: azure, azure-aks, azure-managed-identity

There is a project called `secrets-store-csi-driver-provider-azure` that allows to use a managed identity to get secrets from azure key vault.

If I understand correctly the pods running by that provider do have access to the identity, e.g. kubelet identity created by the AKS.

Does that mean that any pod running in AKS can do the same?

I assume the answer should be "no", but I'd like to understand what gives the provider an ability to access identity that the other pods do not posess. Perhaps it's some privileged access to node?

Comment: I'm not sure whether your question is how to use MSI, but there is pod identity for that https://github.com/Azure/aad-pod-identity

Comment: It's not quite about aad-pod-identity, I am wondering on security how and what gives some pods a possibility to assume an identity. Would not any pod be able to do the same then?

Comment: I don't know about the CSI driver but pod identity works by adding certain annotations to your pods that you want to assume the identity

Comment: I was wondering how a pod does get the access to identity, not in yaml manifests, but technically obtaining the rights to assume this identity